# Clicked item copy to clipboard

Tags: javascript

I have three span with same class

```
<div>
    <span class="textValue">Atul</span>
    <span class="textValue">Kumar</span>
    <span class="textValue">Rajput</span>
</div>
```

I just want that, If I click on any of the spans, then the value of that span will be copied to the clipboard.

i.e. if I click on first span then "Atul" will be copied into the clipboard.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_copy_clipboard.asp

Comment: Have you even tried to tackle this on your own? https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_copy_clipboard.asp
If yes post the code you wrote so we can fix it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I copy to the clipboard in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-do-i-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not select a `span` so you have to create a temporary `textarea` with the `textContent` of the span to execute the `copy` command.

```html
<div>
    <span class="textValue" onClick="copy(this)">Atul</span>
    <span class="textValue" onClick="copy(this)">Kumar</span>
    <span class="textValue" onClick="copy(this)">Rajput</span>
</div>
<p/>
Try to paste the text that you copied:
<br/>
<input type="text"/>
 <p/>
<span id="result"></span>
<script>
var result = document.getElementById("result");
function copy(el){
  var copyText = el.textContent;
    var textArea = document.createElement("textarea");
    textArea.value =  copyText;
    document.body.appendChild(textArea);
    textArea.select();
    document.execCommand("Copy");
   textArea.remove();
   result.innerHTML = "Copied text: "+copyText;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
 $(".textValue").click(function () {
    var spanVal = $(this).text();
    document.execCommand("copy");
    alert(spanVal);
});
```

Comment: jQuery's `live()` method was removed in jQuery version 1.9. You should use `on()` instead. Also, your method does not work.

Answer (score -2):

You can try [this codepen](https://codepen.io/ankit567/pen/vaNxjB) for different layout

OR

[This Codepen](http://www.sitepoint.com/)

this way

```js
const span = document.querySelector("span");
var result = document.getElementById("result");
function copy(el){
  var copyText = el.textContent;
    var textArea = document.createElement("textarea");
    textArea.value =  copyText;
    document.body.appendChild(textArea);
    textArea.select();
    document.execCommand("Copy");
   textArea.remove();
   result.innerHTML = "Copied text: "+copyText;
}
</script>
```

```html
<div>
    <span class="textValue"  onClick="copy(this)">Atul</span>
    <span class="textValue"  onClick="copy(this)">Kumar</span>
    <span class="textValue"  onClick="copy(this)">Rajput</span>
</div>

<span id="result"></span>
```